# How does dotenv cli with "--" (double-dash) running commands?

Tags: powershell, shell, command-line, dotenv, pnpm

Im my project i am trying to use dotenv-cli with pnpm. I am using PowerShell 7.2.1 on windows. I have monorepo with package `api` with script `dev` in `package.json`.
First what I tried was:

```sh
dotenv -e .\.env -- pnpm dev --filter api
```

And it did not work:

```
 ERR_PNPM_RECURSIVE_EXEC_FIRST_FAIL  not found: dev
```

But when I tried:

```sh
dotenv -e .\.env -- pnpm -- dev --filter api
```

It worked well.

As I had read `--` signifies the end of command options, after which only positional arguments are accepted. So why do I need to use it twice for my command to work? Why is it working like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you call *from PowerShell* (unlike from `cmd.exe`), **the command name `dotenv`  resolves to a *PowerShell script*, namely `dotenv.ps1`**, as you report.

**When PowerShell calls a PowerShell-*native* command - including `.ps1` files -  its own parameter binder interprets the (first) `--` argument and *removes it*; that is, the target command *never sees it***.
(The semantics of `--` is analogous to that of Unix utilities: `--` tells the parameter binder to treat subsequent arguments as *positional* ones, even if they *look like parameter (option) names*, such as `-foo`.)

**Thus, unfortunately, you need to specify `--` *twice* in order to pass a single `--` instance through to the `.ps1` script itself:**

```sh
# The first '--' is removed by PowerShell's parameter binder.
# The second one is then received as an actual, positional argument by
# dotenv.ps1
dotenv -e .\.env -- -- pnpm dev --filter api
```

Alternatively, assuming that `dotenv.cmd`, i.e. a *batch file* version of the CLI exists too (and is also in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`), you can bypass this problem by calling it explicitly, instead of the `.ps1`; **when calling *external programs* (including scripts interpreted by other shells / scripting engines, such as `cmd.exe`), PowerShell does *not* remove `--`**:

```sh
# Calling the batch-file form of the command doesn't require
# passing '--' twice.
dotenv.cmd -e .\.env -- pnpm dev --filter api
```

*Caveat*: While it will typically not matter, the way a batch file parses its arguments differs from how PowerShell does it for its native commands.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Between for dotenv there exist there executables: `dotenv`, `dotenv.ps1` and `dotenv.CMD`. And for pnpm only two executables: `pnpm` and `pnpm.CMD`.

Comment: Understood @valerii15298; the extension-less variants aren't truly executable on Windows, and when a name without extension is invoked as a command, PowerShell gives precedence to a `.ps1` file by that name (over other executable extensions such as `.cmd`).